# MongoDB poor write speed for collection with 500K documents with pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

**System Information**: 
**OS**: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
**System**: 80 GB RAM, 1 TB SSD, i7-12700k

The documents in this collection are on average 16KB, and there are 500K documents in this collection. I noticed that as the collection grows larger, the time taken to insert documents also grows larger.

[image: Linear relationship?]

**In what ways could I improve the speed of writes?**

It is taking 10 Hours to insert 150k documents. Which is around what the graph predicted when we integrate the line:

```
def f(num):
    return 0.0004*num+0.9594

sum=0
for i in range(500,650):
    sum+=f(i*1000)

>> sum/3600
>> 9.61497
```

**Potential upgrades in my mind:**

- Use the C++ mongo engine for writes
- Allocate more RAM to Mongod

**Logs**

`iotop` showing mongod using < 1% of the IO capacity with write speeds around 10-20 KB/s

`htop` showing the mongod is only using ~ 16GB of RAM \

Disks showing that some 300GB of SSD is free

**EDIT**:

Psudo code:

```py
docs=[...]
for doc in docs:
   doc["last_updated"]=str(datetime.now())
   
   doc_from_db = collection.find_one({"key":doc["key"]})
   
   new_dict = minify(doc)
   if doc_from_db is None:
      collection.insert_one(new_dict)
   else:
      collection.replace_one({"key":doc["key"]},new_dict,upsert=true)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it comes to writes there are a few things to consider, the most impactful one which I'm assuming is the issue here is index size / index complexity / unique indexes.

It's hard to give exact advice without more information so I'll detail the most common bottlenecks when it comes to writes from my experience.

1. As mentioned indexes, if you have too many indexes. unique indexes. or indexes on very large arrays (and the document you insert have large arrays) these all heavily impact insert performance. This behavior also correlates with the graph you provided as inserting becomes worse and worse the larger the index gets. There is no "real" solution to this issue, you should reconsider which indexes and which indexes cause the bottleneck (focus on unique /array indexes). For example if you have an index that enforces uniqueness then drop it and enforce uniqueness at the application level instead.
2. write concern and replication lag, if you are using a replica set and you require a majority write concern this can definitely cause issues due to the sync lag that happens and grows, usually this is a side affect of a different issues, for example because of #1 (large indexes) the insert takes too long which causes sync lag which delays even further the write concern.
3. unoptimized hardware (Assuming you're hosted on cloud), you'd be surprised how much you can optimize write performance by just changing the disk type and increasing IOPS. this will give immediate performance. obviously at the cost of $$$.
4. no code was provided so I would also check that, if it's a for loop then obviously you can parallelize the logic.

I recommend you test the same insert logic on an indexless collection to pinpoint the problem, i'd be glad to help think of other issues/solutions once you can provide more information.

---

EDIT:

Here is an example of how to avoid the `for` loop issue by using `bulkWrite` instead in python using `pymongo`.

```
from pymongo import InsertOne, DeleteOne, ReplaceOne
from pymongo.errors import BulkWriteError

docs = [... input documents ]
requests = []
for doc in docs:
    requests.append({
       ReplaceOne({"docId": doc["docID"]}, doc, { upsert: True})
   })

try:
    db.docs.bulk_write(requests, ordered=False)
except BulkWriteError as bwe:
    pprint(bwe.details)
```

Comment: Thanks for your datialed response. Unfortunately, I cannot share the source code (its propritory) but It does consist of a python for loop. 
In addition, inside the for loop it checkes whether the document to be inserted already exists in the collection with a `find_one`, if so `replace_one` or `insert_one`. 

The only index in the collection is the `_id` and its around **9.6MB**. Not sure wheteher to change this. 

I am profiling my code to see which specific mongo query is the bottleneck. 

The mongod collection is hosted locally with 80GB RAM and a alderlake CPU so no issues there

Comment: It sounds like we can optimize the code quite a bit then, could you share a puesdo code sample?

Comment: I added a sample in python on how to avoid the bottleneck, using a for loop is definitely a bad idea as each request delays the others. Additionaly instead of doing find -> insert or replace you can just use replaceOne with `upsert=True` to achieve the same logic.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. I have Added the puesdo code sample

Comment: For simple inserts you should use `insert_many`. `buik_write` is really only used where the operations are a mix of inserts, updates and deletes.

Comment: `bulk_write` should be used when you have many operations and want to save on network, regardless if you have a mix or not. in this case insert many does not improve performance because he needs to execute a find query for each of them prior to determine if to execute an insert or an update.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable profiling in Database, but according to previous comments and your code, just python code profiling may be enough, for example can you show the output of similar example?
https://github.com/Tornike-Skhulukhia/cprofiler_python_example/blob/main/demo.py

But before that, please check that you have index on field that you are doing searches against using find_one command in current code, otherwise database may need to do full collection scan to just find 1 document, meaning if you have more documents, this time will also increase a lot.

Comment: I Discovered your second point yesterday. All I had to do was create an (asceding index?!) for the key that I was querying. Without any refactoring, mongo writes are fast. One thing I am still confused about is why should the index type be asceding when the key is a string?

Comment: If you are doing searches using only one field, it does not matter if index is ascending or descending as Mongo can traverse it forwards or backwards. Ascending index can be used for descending sort for example.

Comment: I was more confused about why creating a text index for a text key was so slow compared to Ascending or Descending index

Comment: If you want to query text values using words from the text, instead of full values, text index is more useful, but creating and maintaining it will be more costly as it needs stemming and stopwords removal and indexing individual words https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-text/#index-entries